# Can an Alchemist really get shut down by a shatter spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, alchemist

Your standard alchemist in Pathfinder usually uses vials for their bombs, mixtures, and everything else. Suppose said alchemist was hit or in an area of effect [shatter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shatter) spell.

Since they are on his person they would not be unattended and thus be given the holders save. This would still be a will save (which makes no sense to me).

Of course this doesnt work if they are using iron vials or something similar.

Have I understood this situation correctly? Is an alchemist truly so vulnerable to shatter?

Comment: So what's the question exactly? Seems like you've worked out some pretty horrifying (and accurate) implications for alchemists vs shatter.

Comment: I was wondering if I was missing something because a 2nd level spell shouldnt be able to so completely nerf a single character who has such low will saves.
I was also making sure that the area of effect still affected attended objects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've misunderstood how **Shatter** works.

You only have one of two options when casting the spell:

1) **Area of Effect:**

> Used as an area attack, shatter destroys non-magical objects of crystal, glass, ceramic, or porcelain. All such unattended objects within a 5-foot radius of the point of origin are smashed into dozens of pieces by the spell. [Source (PFSRD)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shatter)

This *only* effects unattended objects and therefore would not effect anything your alchemist is carrying.

2) **Targeted:**

> Alternatively, you can target shatter against a single solid non-magical object, regardless of composition, weighing up to 10 pounds per caster level. Targeted against a crystalline creature (of any weight), shatter deals 1d6 points of sonic damage per caster level (maximum 10d6), with a Fortitude save for half damage. [Source (PFSRD)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shatter)

This may only target *one* object, or one *crystaline* creature, so doesn't affect the Alchemist.This part of the description doesn't mention whether or not the object must be unattended. Your DM could rule that one attended object could be targeted but then it would still be granted a save, using the Alchemist's Fortitude or Will (I leave this to DM discretion because this doesn't seem like the intended effect of the spell). All in all, if you're DM allows it, using Shatter against an Alchemist would not be much different from sundering a Fighter's weapon.

Comment: So as I feared, the area of effect is only for unattended objects

Comment: Is that as you feared? I thought your fear was that it would totally nerf the alchemist? In this reading, the Alchemist comes out fine.

Comment: Im the DM in this case, not the alchemist, so a matter of perspective, lol.